# slide down menu on scroll bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried everything possible to create a transparent navbar that 
    animates 
    when scrolling down the webpage. the markup i've included here is from 
    another person on here that was wanting the same type of navbar but i tried 
    it and it didn't work. So after lots of attempts, I'm completely out of 
    options. Can anyone offer any suggestions ? thanks in advance.
My HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg" data- toggle="affix">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="myofficiallogo.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
    aria-expanded="false" aria- label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My css

```
.navbar {
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s ease;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease;
  }

  .affix {
    padding-top: 0.2em !important;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em !important;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
    transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  }

  section {
    min-height: calc(100% - 70px);
  }
```

My js:

```
$('[data-toggle="affix"]').each(function() {
  var ele = $(this),
  wrapper = $('<div></div>');

  ele.before(wrapper);
  $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    toggleAffix(ele, $(this), wrapper);
  });

  // init
  toggleAffix(ele, $(window), wrapper);
});
```

Comment: `data- toggle="affix"`, `data- target="#navbarNav"`, `aria- label="Toggle navigation"`. Just so you know.

Comment: ^ Yup, these spaces are not supposed to be there. Are you missing the code for the toggleAffix function in your .js? That function should add or remove a class based on the value of $window.scrollTop() to allow styles to change when you scroll. I don't fully understand what you want to do here though.

Comment: Ok so i've created a transparent navbar with z-index so only the menu links (no navbar) and logo are showing over the header image, now i'm trying to create a menu bar so when a user starts scrolling down, a black menu bar appears over the menu links, and so far it hasn't been possible to achieve. I hope this explanation helps.